# Dicussion for X-vectors

Tags: deep-learning, embeddings

I am posting this question to ask some questions regarding the X-vector embedding proposed by Synder et al.

The paper is [X-VECTORS: ROBUST DNN EMBEDDINGS FOR SPEAKER RECOGNITION](https://www.danielpovey.com/files/2018_icassp_xvectors.pdf)

With reference to the following table, the network was built using `Time Delay Neural Network` for the frame level. It is suggested that the input acoustic features (feature dimension is 24) are frame splices. So for `frame1 layer`, the input features are actually `t-2, t-1, t, t+1, t+2` spliced (mentioned in his another paper "Deep Neural Network Embeddings for Text-Independent Speaker Verification"). This can be understood so it shows 5 in the total context and the input is `120x512`.    `5 * 24 = 120` .

[image]

**Here is my quotation from the paper**

> "The DNN configuration is outlined in Table 1. Suppose an input
> segment has T frames. The first five layers operate on speech frames,
> with a small temporal context centered at the current frame t. For
> example, the input to layer frame3 is the spliced output of frame2, at
> frames t - 3, t and t + 3. This builds on the temporal context of the
> earlier layers so that frame3 sees a total context of 15 frames."

Here comes my questions,

1. what is the `512`? is it the hidden unit for the TDNN?
2. What are the 9 and 15 `context` in `frame 2` and `frame 3 level`? It is confusing And how do we get the `1536` dimension